# SOAP UI detailed reporting

Tags: soapui, reporting

I'm using SOAP UI pro

I have a testCase that uses DataSource to run n-times the same testCase with different parameters.

This works fine but, when I print the testResults report, I get 1 line with PASS or FAILED.

Is there any way to configure reporting so I can get the information that, for example, it failed at the xth iteration ?

thank you

Alexandre

Comment: you can use junit-style report and print some error messages in groovy script.. so when you open the junit style report. you can see what are the errors.. in that report.